# Worksheets with Big Numbers

Tags: pgfmath

I am trying to make mental math worksheets with exercises such as

> 25% of 80 trillion is ___

It seems that `pgf` and/or `pgfmath` is not capable of doing this as the numbers are too large. The code compiles with smaller numbers.

How should I do this?

When I figure out what's going on, I'll switch to random numbers that generate exercises and solutions worksheets, but I believe the MWE below demonstrates the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\Product}{int(20000*50000)}

\Product

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's a hard limit in TeX. You can't exceed that limit. You could do the calculations not in TeX and then typeset the results.

Comment: The [sagetex](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/sagetex/sagetex.pdf) package gives you access to a computer algebra system, SAGE, which can handle all the mathematics. [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/) is the easiest way to get started. Search `sagetex` on this site for examples.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `xfp` or `xint`. For the above purpose they have the advantage that they can yield expandable expressions. `pgf` also works with the `fpu` library (and also with the `fixedpointarithmetic` library together with the `fp` package, but the latter is arguably superseded by `xfp`). Here is one example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xfp}

\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}

\fpeval{20000*50000}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Eventually, I want to create worksheets that use random numbers to generate exercises and solutions. How well can `xfp` handle that? How about `xint`?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything Random numbers are implemented in both. In `xfp` there are `randint(m, n)` and `rand()`, try e.g. `\fpeval{rand()}` or `\fpeval{randint(2,7)}`. The perhaps biggest drawback of `xfp` is the quality of its documentation. If you use `texdoc xfp` you get something that lets you sort of guess what's going on, but not even the function names are typeset consistently. You *can* look up the details with `texdoc l3fp`, but this is not necessarily written for those who do not know much about `l3`.

Answer (score 3):

**DISCLAIMER:** This only works with LuaTeX and only with integers.

If you want to work with arbitrary-precision integers, a pure Lua module which handles very well with otherwise difficult cases is [`lua-nums`](https://github.com/user-none/lua-nums). You need to download `bn.lua` and put it in the same folder as your main file.

I've avoided parsing, but you could look at [LPEG](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/%7Eroberto/lpeg/) for more advanced examples. For the moment, basic operations (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `^`, `//`, `%`) and binary operators (`&`, `|`, `>>`, `<<`, `~`, `|`) should work, although passing special characters to Lua is kinda a pain. There's a trade-off between cumbersome typing and speed of operations as `lua-nums` runs smoothly.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{geometry}
%\geometry{paperwidth=100mm,paperheight=85mm,margin=2em}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
userdata = userdata or {}
--bn.lua should be in the same folder as \jobname.tex
userdata.bn = require"bn"
userdata.evaluatebn = function(s)
    return load("return ".. s:gsub("%d+", "userdata.bn(%1)"))()
end
\end{luacode*}
\newcommand{\evaluatebn}[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(tostring(userdata.evaluatebn("#1")))}}
\begin{document}
\section{Rationale}
In Spanish and English (long scale), a trillion stands for $10^{18}$: \evaluatebn{10^18}.

%Integer division, so // and / are interchangeable
25\% of 80 trillion (long scale) is \evaluatebn{80*10^18//4}

25\% of 80 trillion (short scale) is \evaluatebn{80*10^12//4}

\section{Some other examples}
\begin{itemize}
\item $2^{70} = \evaluatebn{1 << 70}$
% \string& instead of Lua's &
\item $47542121789123 = 4\times\evaluatebn{(47542121789123 >> 2)} + \evaluatebn{(47542121789123 \string& 3)}$
\item $15! = \evaluatebn{1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10*11*12*13*14*15}$
% \csstring\% instead of Lua's %
\item $47542121789\% 4787973 = \evaluatebn{(47542121789 \csstring\% 4787973)}$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]